# Aladdin's wishes and a logical fallacy

Tags: magical-theory, disney, aladdin

In Aladdin, since the wish to be a Prince was not really granted, shouldn't he have had 2 wishes left, able to free the genie and have a wish for himself? Ie, is that a logical plot hole?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/69385/4918 Aladdin: Why Did Wishes Get Revoked?

Comment: Here's the Nome King's analogy for a similar situation in *[Ozma of Oz](http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/L_Frank_Baum/Ozma_of_Oz/The_Nome_King_p4.html)*: "Now suppose, my dear, that I gave you a pretty doll in exchange for a lock of your hair, and that after you had received the doll you smashed it into pieces and destroyed it. Could you say that I had not given you a pretty doll? And could you, in fairness, ask me to return to you the lock of hair, just because you had smashed the doll? Of course not." The wish to be a Prince was really granted; it just had its effects reversed by Jafar.

Answer (score 28):

The Genie does make him a [Prince](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEryAoLfnAA) but Jafar uses magic to turn him from Prince Ali *back* into plain old Aladdin:

> Yes, meet a blast from your past
>   Whose lies were too good to last
>   Say
>   hello to your precious Prince Ali!
>
> **(JAFAR zaps ALI back to ALADDIN.)** - <sub><sup>[Aladdin Disney Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Aladdin.html)</sup></sub>

The genie confirms that Aladdin will need to use another wish if he wants to become Prince Ali again.

> **GENIE:**  (Wipes away a tear)  Al, no problem. You've still got one wish
>   left.  Just say the word and you're a prince **again**.

---

It's pure guesswork but since the Prince Ali persona is effectively dead (killed by Jafar), this would fall well within the rules and guidelines issued by the Genie;

> "No Substitutions, exchanges **or refunds"**

and

> **"I can't bring people back from the dead.**  It's not a pretty picture"

Answer (score 3):

To be correct:

Alladin tricks the genie into getting him out of the cave. Hence no wish was used.
Alladin then wishes to be turned into a Prince. Hence the first wish.

After the guards throw Alladin in the sea, Alladin 'rubs' the lamp — hence the second wish.

> GENIE:  Never fails.  Get in the bath and there's a rub at the lamp.
>   (Squeaks the duck)  Hello.
>   (Sees unconscious ALADDIN) Al?  Al!  Kid, snap out of it! You can't cheat on this one!  I can't help you unless you make a wish.  You have to say  "Genie I want you to save my life."  Got it?  Okay.  C'mon Aladdin!!
>   (He grabs ALADDIN by the shoulders and shakes him.  His head goes up, then falls.)  I'll take that as a yes.
>   (Head turns into a siren.) Wooga!  Wooga!
>   (Turns into a submarine.)  Up scope!
>   (He babbles in something that sounds like German.  On the surface, a giant water spout emerges, and lands on top of the cliff.  ALADDIN reawakes and coughs the water out of his lungs.) Don't you scare me like that!
>   ALADDIN:    Genie, I--uh, I-uh...(He can't think of how to say it, so they just hug each other.)  Thanks, Genie.
>   GENIE:  Oh, Al.  I'm gettin' kind of fond of you, kid.  Not that I want to pick out curtains or anything.

The last wish then would be Alladin's choice to become a Prince or to free Genie.

Alas: A wish is a certain change of the moment.

- I wish for a car, BANG, there is a car.
- I wish the car to be removed, BANG, no more car.

You know have succesfully used two wishes. The second to alter/delete the first.

Also: Something that occurred to me with wishes as also seen in a [Fairy oddparents](http://fairlyoddparents.wikia.com/wiki/Genie_Meanie_Minie_Mo) show, a wish could be freely interpreted by the genie.

- Is something like the added statement for handicapped persons: ie. a handicapped person without a leg should wear his prostathic limb while driving. It doesn't says where it must be worn.