# Aladdin: Why Did Wishes Get Revoked?

Tags: disney, aladdin-1992

In the 1992 Disney adaptation of Aladdin, by my count, at least two wishes get revoked without explanation.

1. Aladdin becoming a prince gets revoked.  Somehow.  The answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67154/aladdins-wishes-and-a-logical-fallacy) suggests that Jafar zapped him back to being a peasant, but I'm not sure that makes sense.  It looked like Jafar was just *revealing* Aladdin to be a peasant--not transforming him back.  Keep in mind, at this point, Jafar is still less powerful than the genie, and it took the genie several minutes to do the *forward* transformation.
2. Jafar's wish of being Sultan gets revoked.  And, in this case, there isn't *any* explanation I can think of.  After Jafar wishes to become Sultan, he wishes to become the most powerful sorcerer.  He never *gives up* being Sultan.  Yet, somehow at the end of the movie, the real Sultan has his clothes back (how did *that* happen, anyway?), and he's Sultan again!

The question is: what justifies these?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67154/4918 Aladdin's wishes and a logical fallacy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The script is very clear on the first point. Jafar doesn't just remove his Aladdin's fancy clothes, he fully reverts him to being a peasant: He literally zaps [Prince] ALI back to [commoner] ALADDIN:

> Yes, meet a blast from your past
>   Whose lies were too good to last
>   Say
>   hello to your precious Prince Ali!
>
> **(JAFAR zaps ALI back to ALADDIN.)** - <sub><sup>[Aladdin Disney Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Aladdin.html)</sup></sub>

In the second case, Jafar doesn't just wish to become the most powerful sorcerer in the world (which he already is, courtesy of wish #2) but to literally become a genie. Now, I appreciate that there's no logical reason why you couldn't be both a sultan *and* a genie but the phrasing of the wish suggests he no longer wishes to be merely the sultan, he now wants to be a genie **instead**

> **JAFAR:**  *Slave, I make my third wish!  I wish to be an all
>           powerful genie!*
>
> **GENIE:**  (Reluctantly) *All right, your wish is my command.
>           Way to go, Al.*

If we assume that Jafar stops being the Sultan, then the rightful Sultan would then resume his title and position (and because people need to see this visual change, get his clothes back too).

Comment: Zapping 'Ali' back to 'Aladdin' seems even more confusing! Does this mean that in fulfilling the actual wish, Genie had actually swapped Aladdin with some existing Prince in the minds of people who knew that Prince? Or conjured up a princedom/kingdom full of folks who thought Aladdin was their very own Prince Ali?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it's the latter. He turns up with a retinue of followers.

Comment: Just because someone makes you a prince doesn't stop someone else from taking it away.  Just because I might give you $100, doesn't stop the guy around the corner from mugging you and taking your $100.

Comment: Hey, I have a logical reason you can't be both a sultan and a genie:  genies are slaves stuck in lamps. Can't rule the sultanate if you can't exercise that PHENOMONAL COSMIC POWER without enslaving yourself to anyone who rubs your lamp to get you out of your itty bitty living space.

Answer (score 9):

I always interpreted it like this:

Aladdin's wish is granted, he becomes a prince. The wish is now *complete* and everything else is **up to him**. As a prince now, Aladin can mess up and get exposed and lose his "prince-status" (just like in real life).

The other one, where Jaffar is no longer sultan when he becomes a genie, it's the same thing. He was made sultan, but he neglected his sultan duties (and then disappeared into a lamp) so no one knew where the current sultan went. The country needed a new leader, it makes sense to just reinstate the old one (even though he seems to have the mind of a 5 year old).